# Clipboard sharing broke under MacOS X

Tags: terminal, os-clipboard, macos

I'm using (roughly) the same config for my mac and my ubuntu machine. I use

```
set clipboard=unnamed,unnamedplus
```

To conveniently share vim's clipboard with the system clipboard. However, lately the clipboard sharing broke under Mac OS X.

I have no idea what I did to break it, it still works fine under ubuntu. I've tried completely removing and reinstalling vim (via homebrew), deleting my `.vimrc` and `.zshrc` files, and still it doesn't seem to work.

Now, when I have

```
set clipboard=unnamed,unnamedplus
```

I cannot paste at all with vim. When I set

```
set clipboard=
```

then I can at least paste in vim, but of course it doesn't share the system clipboard (duh). Using `:reg` confirms that with anything other than `set clipboard=`, nothing is written to vim's registers. `:version` gives me `+clipboard` and `+xterm_clipboard`. I've also tried it in iTerm2 and Terminal.app, both in and outside of tmux (same results). Also, manually copying to the registers (`"*yy`, `"+yy`) didn't work.

Interestingly, the the GUI-version (MacVim `7.4-74`, also installed via homebrew) still functions fine in this regard, I can happily copy/paste to/from the system register there.

Do you guys have any ideas? Cause I'm desperate at this point...

Here's my `.vimrc`: https://github.com/DeX3/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc

Comment: Do you use tmux?

Comment: @romainl yes, the error occurs both inside and outside of tmux though

Comment: I would recommend using MacVim instead, as it plays better in Mac OS. You don't have to use the GUI version -- `mvim -v` will work in the terminal.

Comment: @tommcdo in `mvim -v` it works! Both in and outside of tmux! Boy am I glad... I'm just gonna alias that now. No idea what broke it in the first place, but I'm just glad this works. Thanks! If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I have the same issue, also in macvim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### MacVim

Under OS X, it's best to use [MacVim](https://macvim-dev.github.io/macvim/). OS X behaves differently to other operating systems when it comes to things like clipboard management. MacVim is specifically designed to address the areas where Vim falls short on the Mac.

#### Coming to a terminal near you

Although MacVim runs as a GUI (like GVim) by default, you can use MacVim in the terminal using `mvim -v`. I'd recommend an alias such as the following (I'm using bash syntax; adjust according to your shell):

```
alias vim='mvim -v'
```

Comment: Alternatively, use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and run `brew install vim --override-system-vi`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this remap

```
nnoremap y "+y
```

this will yank to the system clipboard
So no need to use MacVim and this works for neovim

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Just a note that your answer only works in normal mode (so `v_y` is unaffected). I suspect the real issue for the OP is either in the config or the use of an outdated version, as `"*y` works for me on a mac with terminal vim.